# How to reduce NET and CPU usage in Private EOS

Tags: eosio.token, cpu, net, private-blockchain

I am trying to setup a private eos for my app, I want to know if there is possible to change the usage of CPU, NET etc in private setup without staking tokens. If YES, then please guide me with the procedure.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I want to setup a local setup of eos, I want that if a user has not staked tokens he can still be able to make transactions on the local network

Answer (score 1):

Easy:
Use eosio.bios instead of eosio.system contract

Advanced:
`newaccount` in eosio.system initializes account's resources with 0.

```
   void native::newaccount( const name&       creator,
                            const name&       newact,
                            ignore<authority> owner,
                            ignore<authority> active ) {
      /* ... */

      user_resources_table  userres( get_self(), newact.value );

      userres.emplace( newact, [&]( auto& res ) {
        res.owner = newact;
        res.net_weight = asset( 0, system_contract::get_core_symbol() );
        res.cpu_weight = asset( 0, system_contract::get_core_symbol() );
      });

      // three zero params mean ram, net and cpu in order
      // you can change these to proper values, or set -1 to make them unlimited
      set_resource_limits( newact, 0, 0, 0 );
   }
```

Comment: Yes, eosio.bios contract works well for me. You'll be able to create accounts, set the producer schedule and get ordered transaction history as per normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just reduce the resources usage if you want to get an alternative and don't have EOS tokens for stake see the [REX](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#system-rex)(Resources Exchange System) in eosio documentation.

Also must watch this video for simple explanation of REX [video](https://youtu.be/mHNexo0GfNo).

For explanation of different REX functionalities see this blog [article](https://www.eoscanada.com/en/rex-a-technical-understanding-from-the-source-code)